# Probando WebService Moodle con Postman

Tags: moodle-api

Estoy haciendo pruebas con la API de Moodle a través del WebService y Postman y tengo una duda. ¿cómo se indican los parámetros en postman?.

Ejemplo:

Estoy ejecutando la función **core_user_get_users** y debo indicar un criterio que es obligatorio. Esto es lo que tengo actualmente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como resultado obtengo el siguiente error:

```
{
    "exception": "invalid_parameter_exception",
    "errorcode": "invalidparameter",
    "message": "Detectado valor de parámetro no válido",
    "debuginfo": "Missing required key in single structure: criteria"
}
```

Entiendo que el valor de key tiene que tener un formato especial. ¿Alguien sabría decirme como indicar los parámetros?.

Esto es lo que indica la documentación:

//the key/value pairs to be considered in user search. Values can not be empty.
Specify different keys only once (fullname => 'user1', auth => 'manual', ...) -
key occurences are forbidden.
The search is executed with AND operator on the criterias. Invalid criterias (keys) are ignored, the search is still executed on the valid criterias.
You can search without criteria, but the function is not designed for it.
It could very slow or timeout. The function is designed to search some specific users.

```
    list of ( 
object {
key string   //the user column to search, expected keys (value format) are:
                                "id" (int) matching user id,
                                "lastname" (string) user last name (Note: you can use % for searching but it may be considerably slower!),
                                "firstname" (string) user first name (Note: you can use % for searching but it may be considerably slower!),
                                "idnumber" (string) matching user idnumber,
                                "username" (string) matching user username,
                                "email" (string) user email (Note: you can use % for searching but it may be considerably slower!),
                                "auth" (string) matching user auth plugin
value string   //the value to search
} 
)
```

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.